# In string replacement function in Haskel

Tags: haskell

Does there exist a function in Haskell such that I can feed it something like

`replace "Hello" "GoodBye" "Hello World"`

and return something like

`"GoodBye World"`

If  such a function does not exist how would I implement it?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this exists or not. To implement it myself, I'd start with a simpler function. Something like `find :: String -> String -> Int` which returns the index of the first string within the second string. You can return a -1 to indicate not found, or return `Maybe Int` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done using the [`replace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.4.0.1/docs/Data-String-Utils.html#v:replace) function provided by `Data.String.Utils`.

Example usage is very similar to your code snippet:

```
ghci> replace "Hello" "Goodbye" "Hello world"
"Goodbye world"
```

Note that this function is provided as part of the [`MissingH`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.4.0.1) package.

Finally, while this is the first result that comes up on an internet search engine, [Hoogle shows](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=replace) many other packages providing this functionality, as well as a few [relevant results](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String-%3EString-%3EString-%3EString) with the same type signature.

Comment: [Hayoo gives a handful of other relevant functions](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Eq+a+%3D%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+) (mainly the *utility-ht* and *extra* ones) if you search for the more general signature `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: That's a good idea, but considering OP is dealing with strings, I'd be inclined to _also_ typeclass-constrain `a` to `Show a`, which [shows up on Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Show+a%2C+Eq+a%29+%3D%3E+%5Ba%5D-%3E%5Ba%5D-%3E%5Ba%5D-%3E%5Ba%5D). `Data.Text`'s `replace` shows up on the first page there.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The extra `Show a` does not change the results on Hoogle, and a `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]` works just fine with the subset of element types that have both `Eq` and `Show`  constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Hmph. I feel like I really should've be answering this lousy question, but I can't resist.

```
replace :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replace _ _ [] = []
replace old new xs@(x':xs')
  | old == front = new ++ replace old new rear
  | otherwise = x' : replace old new xs'
  where
    (front, rear) = splitLength old xs

splitLength :: [a] -> [b] -> ([b], [b])
splitLength [] ys = ([], ys)
splitLength _ [] = []
splitLength (_:xs) (y:ys) =
  let (l,r) = splitLength xs ys
  in (y:l, r)
```

There is plenty of room to improve this simple implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use [replace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.4.0.1/docs/Data-String-Utils.html) as mentioned above but I decided to make my own implementation of that same function (so to speak) mine is a little inneficient in comparison but it achieves the same result non-theless

```
replace :: String -> String -> String -> String
replace x y frase = let find [] [] [] = []
                        find x' y' (h:t) = if h /= y'
                             then h ++ " "++ find x' y' t
                             else x' ++ " "++ find x' y' t
            in if y `elem` words frase
               then find x y (words frase) else frase
```

is late and probably some of the patterns are redundant, all you are required to do is to recursively search for the matching string by braking the frase into words with [words](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) from **Prelude**, eitherway making your own version is always pointless if there is an efficient working version of it, but I thought this would help you understand how to the function works and maybe implement your own version (for fun or to learn).

Comment: Comments: (1) if you are already using `words`, you might as well rejoin words with `lines` rather than inserting `" "` by hand. (2) While this replacing function respectful of word boundaries is different than the `replace` in Jules' answer, it can be implemented in terms of the other one: `replaceWord old new = lines . replace [old] [new] . words`. Rewriting the generalised `replace` from the libraries would be a worthy exercise as well.

Comment: Some of your base cases are wrong. I wouldn't expect `replace "" "" "Hello"` to produce `""`, but that's what your version does.

Comment: Thanks for the advice fellas, fixed it as much as I could, saw the bug in the implementation, and @dupplude I do realize I could implement it that way, but I thought it would be fun just to be a little old school for learning purposes

Comment: You still have base case issues. I don't know if you have other issues. I also don't understand why you care about word boundaries.